# How can I change a default db table name in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm new to Yii2, and I'm trying to toy some with the advanced template. My problem is I'm getting an error when I try to signup or login on default page, and I don't know where to register the correct table name.

```
**Caused by: PDOException**
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxx.user' doesn't exist
in xxx\...\yii2\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php at line 398
```

I have already created models and controllers using Yii, and, as far as I know, it's all OK. My question is: how can I change that "user" table name to the one on my database? I have already changed the `tableName()` method on the ActiveRecord extended class.

```
class Usuario extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'usuario';
    }
...
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your model.

Comment: I hope that code is what you meant. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yii2 has a built in user model which extends active records and implements identity interface. Set your new table name there.

In common\models\User.php

```
 class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
  {

      public static function tableName()
      {
         return 'new_tbl_name';
      }
  ........
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dency. That was the problem and now it's corrected. I hope this helps some other people as well.

Comment: By the way, just to clarify what I did to solve the problem in case other users check this, I went to common\models\User.php and added the tableName() method, for it doesn't come by default.